# What do I do if my render is just black?

Tags: rendering, animation

[here's the link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzse1iknhXveNGdIM1M3OU5Ec2M) I've got a template from the internet and have been trying to render it.  However when I do so, it takes seconds but it's just a 10 second black clip.  Others that have used similar templates say it should take about an hour to render.

What should I do to try to fix this issue?

(I am new to using Blender so any help is appreciated!) [image: Do you see anything alarming about this that I need to change?]

Comment: Also: When I render an image of it, there is color and I can see everything just fine.  It's just when I render the animation it's blank.

Comment: If you upload a blend file, then helping you out would be much easier, as we do not know what the problem is (apart from a black render).

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Have you tried rendering out each frame, then using the sequencer to render an animation?

Comment: I'm so new at this... I have no clue what it is that you mean- I apologize.

Comment: Sorry my internet is being slow. You could add a link to the blend file that you are using.

Comment: When I go to edit, what should I click on to add such a thing? I see hyperlink, block code, and code sample.  Which is correct?

Comment: Here is a tutorial from Blender Guru on how to render through the sequencer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd5RT8rEPqU

Comment: Upload the blend to an outside source, such as google doc or something, and add in a hyperlink in the above question.

Comment: To upload a file please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ .To learn how to upload use the help link on the top right of the page of that site.

Comment: cegaton- It says that my file size is too large to upload to that site

Comment: The link you posted requires the original uploader to allow access to the drive to download. So everyone don't have a file to help you out still ...

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single light source in the file you have downloaded. Just
some animation and a few meshes. All you have to do is to add some
light source and it should render fine.

Hope that helps.